# Materialize Sidenav not working on iOS or iPhone but works on all other devices

Tags: javascript, ios, css, iphone, materialize

Materialize Sidenav not working on iPad or iPhone but on all other devices.  Here is a link to the repo if you want to see the code:  [repo](https://github.com/T-travis/portfolio) see `index.html` (line 44 down) and `js/onloadSetup.js`

I tried adding this in `onloadSetup.js`:

```
$('#menu').on('click', function() {
    $('.sidenav').sidenav('open');
  });
```

but I had no luck.

Tried following this [link](https://github.com/Dogfalo/materialize/issues/2134) but I got no luck. Can someone help me? Thank you!

**UPDATE**:
Hours later it just started working on my iPad.  I don't know what changes
affected it or if any did. I'm guessing it was the above code I added but this code should not be needed.  Anyhow problem solved, I just wish I new why it is now working.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to use the open method on the instance:

```
$('.sidenav').open();
```

Comment: Several hours later it is now working but I don't know why.  I tried on several peoples iPhones and my iPads and it wouldn't work but now it is.  Thanks